# Is every PrintQueue instance (of the same printer) refreshed when I refresh one instance?

Tags: c#, printing, printqueue

When I have two instances of a `PrintQueue` in C#, of the same printer. One I made before I called .refresh(), the other after. I put those `PrintQueue`s in a ArrayList. And rotate them. Yet I get different results, like so:

```
if(arrPrintersOld != null)
{
    arrPrintersOld.Clear();
    arrPrintersOld = null;
}

arrPrintersOld = arrPrinters;

arrPrinters = new ArrayList();

        PrintQueueCollection printQueues = null;

        // PrintServer Class = Manages the print queues on a print server, 
        // which is usually a computer, but can be a dedicated hardware print server appliance.
        PrintServer printServer = new PrintServer();

        printQueues = printServer.GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections });

        foreach (PrintQueue pq in printQueues)
        {

            pq.Refresh();

            arrPrinters.Add(pq);
        }

        if(!blnFirstTimePrinterList)
        {
            comparePrinterLists();

            PrintQueue tempOld = (PrintQueue)arrPrintersOld[0];
            PrintQueue tempNew = (PrintQueue)arrPrinters[0];

            Console.WriteLine("OldPrinter 1 is paused:" + tempOld.IsPaused);
            Console.WriteLine("NewPrinter 1 is paused:" + tempNew.IsPaused);
        }
```

Once I unpause the printer, I get an true at the tempOld.IsPaused, and a false at tempNew.IsPaused;

But when I get pause the printer again, I get a true and tempOld.IsPaused and a true and TempNew.IsPaused?

So does the refresh() function also work at the told instances of am I missing something?

Comment: We need to see some code on how you pause, unpause the printer, if its done from code.

Comment: No I unpause/pause it in Windows (configuration panel)

Comment: System.Printing is an extremely troublesome namespace.  Skipped for the .NET 2.0 release because of quality issues, they couldn't skip it again for 3.0 because WPF took a dependency on it.  Omitted from the reference source, it will not be added to .NETCore.  I *think* the wonky rule is that Refresh() will only refresh properties that you used before.  Do what works, keep fingers crossed.